# create a csv file from file path

Tags: awk

I need to find complete path of files in current directory and then save it to .csv file with path,folder_name

The foler_name is the last directory for e.g. basics, pca and forked in this example...

```
# find .

./pandas_examples/basics/Skin_NoSkin.ipynb
./pandas_examples/basics/data_visual.ipynb
./pandas_examples/pca/README.md
./pandas_examples/pca/PCA-tSNE-AE.ipynb
./pandas_examples/forked/pandas_accidents.py
```

Expected output:

```
./pandas_examples/basics/Skin_NoSkin.ipynb, basics
./pandas_examples/basics/data_visual.ipynb, basics
./pandas_examples/pca/README.md, pca
./pandas_examples/pca/PCA-tSNE-AE.ipynb, pca
./pandas_examples/forked/pandas_accidents.py, forked
```

This format is needed for keras machine learning task.

---

Update:

This seems to work if the target is found in the third column:

```
cat path.txt | cut -d '/' -f3 > target.txt
paste -d "," path.txt target.txt
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Could you please explain here that `pca` has lot of files but your sample output has only 2 entries? Sorry but its not clear, kindly do add more details into your question and let us know then.

Comment: And what if the found line is a directory? What should happen then? Make sure  `expected_output` match the `example_input`

Comment: or, if you do not need directories in your input, use `find . -type f` to filter the directories on input.

Comment: This worked as expected: find . -type f | awk -F "/" 'BEGIN{ OFS=", " }{ print "gs://xx-287804-vcm/img/validation/"$0, $(NF-1) }' | sed 's/\/\.//g' > all_data.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . | awk -F "/" 'BEGIN{ OFS=", " }{ print $0, $(NF-1) }'
```

`-F "/"`  the input is separated by "/"

`OFS=", "` the output is separated by a comma and a space

`print $0, $(NF-1)`  print the inputline (`$0`) and the last, but one, field (`$(NF-1)`)

Answer (score 3):

You may just use this:

```
find . | awk -F/ '{print $0","$3}'
```